# Can't insert data in data property in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to create an array of objects in `hourlyTemperatureData` from looping through all the items in `weatherData.hourly` and filtering some data.

The expected data in `hourlyTemperatureData` is like -
{'abc':123, 'xyz':567,......}

But `this.hourlyTemperatureData.push(data.dt);` is giving me error-

Cannot read property 'hourlyTemperatureData' of undefined

```
      data() {
        return {
          weatherData: "",
          hourlyTemperatureData: "",
        };
      },


computed: {
    getHourlyTemperatureData: function () {
      this.weatherData.hourly.forEach(function (data) {
        data.dt = moment.unix(data.dt).format("LT");
        this.hourlyTemperatureData.push(data.dt);
      });
      return this.hourlyTemperatureData;
    },
  },
```

---

Updated

```
getHourlyTemperatureData: function () {
      let _this = this;
      this.weatherData.hourly.forEach(function (data) {
        data.dt = moment.unix(data.dt).format("LT");
        _this.hourlyTemperatureData[data.dt] = data.temp;
      });
      //return this.hourlyTemperatureData;
      return console.log(this.hourlyTemperatureData);
    },
```

I m trying to return data like { 10:30 PM: 26.97, 11:30 PM: 26.59,... }

But currently I m getting -

[ 10:30 PM: 26.97, 11:30 PM: 26.59, 12:30 AM: 26.02, 1:30 AM: 25.76, 2:30 AM: 25.56, … ]

Comment: `hourlyTemperatureData: ""` this should be array, `hourlyTemperatureData: []`

Comment: added the answer, please check, this inside the `forEach` will not refer to the component object

Comment: did you modify this `hourlyTemperatureData: {}` in data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update you logic as below:

```
data() {
        return {
          weatherData: "",
          hourlyTemperatureData: {}, // modified
        };
      },


computed: {
    setHourlyTemperatureData: function () {
      let tis = this; // modified
      this.weatherData.hourly.forEach(function (data) {
        data.dt = moment.unix(data.dt).format("LT");
        tis.hourlyTemperatureData[data.dt] = your_value;  // modified
      });
      return this.hourlyTemperatureData;
    },
  },
```

Comment: Ok that's fine now. At last I want hourlyTemperatureData is like - {'abc':123, 'xyz':567,......} Where 'abc' should be 'data.dt' and 123 should be another value.

Comment: can you post the `this.weatherData` data. you mean you want it to be object?

Comment: I didn't understand what is the actual and what you are expecting, can you please update in the question and add a comment

Comment: what ever the value that is in `data.temp` will be assigned to `_this.hourlyTemperatureData[data.dt]`. if you need anything else, you need to tell us in a more clear way

Comment: did you modify this `hourlyTemperatureData: {}` in data?